# This Kernal require an x86-64 CPU, but only detected and i686 CPU

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, operating-system, multiboot

I am a beginner in Ubuntu family.I create a new machine in VirtualBox.I try install Ubuntu 13.04

***filename:ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64*** in Oracle VirtualBox application. But i get

this error.

How can i do. Please see my PC Configuration below.

[image]

Comment: I wonder if your PC is 64-bit machine or not. If not then you won't be able to install 64-bit version of Ubuntu. In that case get the 32-bit version of the installer ISO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a 64-bit VM when you create a new virtual machine in VirtualBox.

Comment: I don't see such option when creating a new VM. Where is it?

Comment: Did you install the 64-bit version of VirtualBox? There are a number of conditions that must be fulfilled to install 64-bit guests. See http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#gui-createvm, and http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#intro-64bitguests

Comment: On a Mac there's only one installer, I think it should work on both. Mine is 64-bit. But never mind, I was just curious, while looking for the option to answer. Doesn't matter.